# Entendiendo async/await

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ecmascript-6, async-await

Entorno: sequelize 3.27, node.js 6.1, express

sequelize

```
 Object.hasMany(OtherObject)
```

Tengo el siguiente pedazo de código:

```
//...

await db.Object.create(objectData).then(async (object:any) => {
    //..

    object.update({sharedLink: aUrl}); //no me interesa que sea secuencial

    await request.othersObjects.forEach(async (otherObject:any) => {

        const hr = await db.OtherObject.create(otherObject);
    });

    //aquí el problema
    for(let oo of await db.OtherObject.findAll({attributes:['id'], where: {objectId: object.id}})) {} 

}
```

Mi problema es que no tengo otherObjects con objectId = object.id cuando deberían haber...

Y es porque el create del OtherObject ocurre después del for for(let oo...

Por qué? Si creo que le estoy poniendo await de manera correcta?

Como comentario, al parecer ahora está andando todo poniendo

```
await object.update({sharedLink: aUrl});
```

a pesar de que no me importa que sea secuencial este update.

Comment: puedes cambiar el async/await en tu for por un generator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que **no puedes utilizar await dentro de un bucle for of**. Los iteradores son síncronos y no se pueden mezclar con el formato asíncrono. Es uno de las carencias de la primera implementación de async/await.

Para resolver el problema, hay una propuesta para introducir un for async que usa los nuevos iteradores asíncronos, pero se utiliza algo distinto a lo que tu escribes:

```
for await (let oo of db.OtherObject.findAll({attributes:['id'], where: {objectId: object.id}})) {
  console.log(oo);
}
```

Todavía está en fase experimental, por lo que te propongo buscar primero de manera asíncrona los objetos, y luego iterarlos de forma síncrona:

```
// Si db.OtherObject.findAll devuelve una sola promesa que contiene un array: 
let ObjectList = await db.OtherObject.findAll({attributes:['id'], where: {objectId: object.id}});
// Si db.OtherObject.findAll devuelve un array que contiene una promesa por cada objeto:
// let ObjectList = await Promise.all(db.OtherObject.findAll({attributes:['id'], where: {objectId: object.id}}));

for (let oo of ObjectList){
   console.log(oo);
}
```

Fuente: [For Async Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration)

Comment: Gracias! Lo pruebo y aviso

Comment: Hola, estando en la versión 7.6 de node, pude usar async/await en un bucle for of